# Remove the color of word or keywords when press backspace or delete key in the rich text box

Tags: c#

I have a problem in rich text box control when I press backspace key or delete key then I want to remove the color of keywords( Main, if,else, try ,catch etc).
How I captured the position of caret or cursor in rich text box or to solve this problem any other method.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the Exact problem, that you are getting here.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current position of the caret using RichTextBox.CaretPosition. MSDN linked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx

Something like this would work:

```
//this line goes in your load event
myTextBox.KeyUp += TextBox_KeyUp;

//this function goes wherever you're storing other events for that UI in your app
private void TextBox_KeyUp (object source, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //check for delete or backspace
    if(e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        int caretPosition = myTextBox.CaretPosition;
        //get the current word or whatever and do something with it here
    }
}
```